# order of finit group which has even elements

Tags: group-theory

I have a question,

prove that a finite group has an even number of elements, if and only if the group consists of an element of order $2$.

Comment: No group consists of an element of order $2$, since the identity has order $1$.

Comment: You mean `contains an` not `consists of an`.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many many times on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The identity element is the only element which has order 1. So assume $g \neq g^{-1}$ for all $g \neq e$ in the group. Then show that the size of the group is odd, since inverses are uniquely determined and the identity element is also in the group.